# If Monero was sent to an address, do I have to wait to actually "see" the funds before transferring

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I changed bitcoin to Monero on Changelly, and got a successful transaction notice from Changelly.

I have the address that Changelly sent the funds to (it's supposed to be at my wallet, but because my wallet won't synch up, I can't "see" the funds.

Here's the question:  If I know the address that Changelly sent the funds to, could I just use that address as a send off point, and direct the funds away from my wallet over to, say, my wallet at coinbase?

Hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is because your address is not actually written to the blockchain. Think of address as an instruction. The sender read that instruction, and put the money in a special envelope hidden among all others. He didn't write an address on it, otherwise everyone could tell it was for your address. Instead, he wrote a little secret and only your wallet knows how to recognize it, but it needs to scan the whole blockchian. To spend it, you need to find it first, open it, and make a new TX from what you recovered.